# Render variable in Livewire/Blade component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have a table with multiple modals and I am trying to test passing in the row id on the loop to ensure my modal is working properly. But I cannot get the value of the variable to show through my Livewire component.

**Livewire Component**

```
<livewire:dashboard.actions :apt_id="$appointments->id"/>
```

**Livewire/dashboard/actions.blade.php**

```
<div><button wire:click="showModal">Show modal</button>

<x-jet-dialog-modal wire:model="showingModal">
    <x-slot name="title">
        {{ __('Delete Account') }}
    </x-slot>
    <x-slot name="content">
        {{ $apt_id }}
    </x-slot>
    <x-slot name="footer">
        <x-jet-secondary-button wire:click="$toggle('showingModal')" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
            {{ __('Nevermind') }}
        </x-jet-secondary-button>

        <x-jet-danger-button class="ml-2" wire:click="deleteUser()" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
            {{ __('Delete Account') }}
        </x-jet-danger-button>
    </x-slot>
</x-jet-dialog-modal></div>
```

**Livewire/Dashboard/Actions.php**

```
class Actions extends Component {

public $showingModal = '';
public $apt_id;


public function mount($apt_id)
{
    $this->apt_id = $apt_id;
}

public function showModal()
{
    $this->showingModal = true;
}

public function render()
{

    return view('livewire.dashboard.actions');
}}
```

Comment: Are you sure its passing the value you assume it is? Do a `dd($apt_id);` inside your `mount()` method to check.

Answer (score 0):

It was because I needed to remove `mount()` and change the variable to camelCase.